# Finding the sum of the following

Tags: python

I am trying to find  x=Σ 1/(2^k) with an upper limit of N and lower limit of k, but I don't know how to add the previous numbers to the current sum.

```
N=input("insert value for N")
N=int(N)
x=1/2**N
while 1<N:
    sum=0
    sum=sum+x
    print(x)
    break 
else:
    print("wrong value of N,N must be greater than 1")
```

Comment: `sum(2**(-k) for k in range(N))`. Note: `sum` is a built-in function. don't use it as a variable. Depending on what you need the range may be `range(1, N+1)`. also note that there is a direct formula for this...

Comment: What's the point of resetting `sum = 0` every time before you add `x` to it? Also don't call your variables `sum` or other builtins. Also python doesn't work like this. You can't set `x` once, then reset `N` and expect `x` to have changed. `x` needs to be recalculated. Also if you don't change `N`, the `while 1 < N` condition is always true and you'll never exit the loop. Actually scratch that. You'll only ever do one iteration of your loop because there's an unconditional `break` at the end of it.

Comment: How can the lower limit be k? k is a variable in the sum. Do you mean 1?

Comment: Since you seem to be a beginner, here are some helpful links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Knowing how to debug your own code is a crucial skill for a programmer to have.

Comment: yes, in this case k=1

Comment: @jackie321 Based on your clarification, I have posted an answer. Please check that and let me know if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```python
while True:
    try:
        N = int(input("Insert value for N: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That was no valid integer.  Try again...")

k = 1
summation = 0

for i in range(k, N+1):
    summation = summation + 1/(2**i)

print(summation)
```

Example output:

```python
>>> insert value for N: 2
0.75
```

This code even checks if you are providing an integer or not. Also, it will not proceed if you provide any integer less than 1. If you provide an integer less than 1, then the loop will not proceed and summation will remain zero. If `N` is greater than 1, the for-loop will add the previous sum to the current sum through `summation = summation + 1/(2 ** i)`, where summation is zero at the start and it will keep adding new sum (`1/(2**i)`) to itself after each iteration.

### Approach without using for-loop and range

Without using `for` and `range`, you can also achieve this using `while` as follows:

```python
N = int(input("Insert value for N: "))

k = 1
summation = 0

while k <= N:
    summation = summation + 1/(2**k)
    k = k + 1

if N < 1:
    print("wrong value of N,N must be greater than 1")
else:
    print(summation)
```

In this approach, we start with `k` being 1. Then we check the `while` loop until `k` is less than or equal to `N`. When the condition is not met, we take the sum as `1/(2**k)` and add it to the previous number (`summation`). We also increment `k` plus one each iteration so that the loop does not become infinite. When `k` gets greater than `N`, the loop breaks.

Comment: 1. Integer validation is irrelevant to the question. 2. If `N < 1`, you'd never enter the `for` loop in the first place because that `range()` would be empty, so it's not necessary to check this condition and break. 3. You haven't explained the useful part of your solution. Even if it's obvious to you why it needs to be done this way, it's best to explain since OP had a problem with it.

Comment: is there anyway to code this without using for and range? since I haven't been taught that yet.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You are right. I have edited my answer to explain to OP the useful part where he is asking how to add the previous sum to the current sum.

Comment: @jackie321 Please see my answer again. I have edited it and included a new approach to achieve this without using `for` or `range`.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for, now if I want do add that if user inserts a value of N which is less than k the program breaks and prints that the value of N must be greater than k (which is one) what should I do

Comment: @jackie321 This is already implemented in the above while-loop approach.  If N is less than k (which is 1) then the while-loop will not proceed. So you don't have to break explicitly!

Answer (score -1):

```
# taking integer value as an input
N=int(input("insert value for N"))
#defining sum
sum1=0
#checking if n is greater than 1
if 1<N:
    for i in range(0,N):#running a loop to add
        x=1/(2**i)#calculating x
        sum1=sum1+x#adding the summation value
    print(sum1)
else:
    print("wrong value of N,N must be greater than 1")
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with some explanation.

Comment: ...and correct syntax and indentations...

Answer (score -1):

Considering the formula you gave in your problem description:

```
k = 10  #lower limit
N = 100 #upper limit
x = sum(1/(2**i) for i in range(k,N+1))
print(x)
```

Comment: Not the downvote, but this only sums `k -> N-1`.

Comment: yes, because as it is explicitly said, k is lower limit and N upper limit. The intention was to reproduce what he wanted, not to do data validation anyway

Comment: The OP included a sigma notation of their formula. Sigma notations have an inclusive upper boundary `range()` has an exclusive boundary. This doesn't reproduce what they asked for... that's not really data validation?

Comment: ah ok, sure, added +1 to N now, thanks